# How to check if element exists in a linked list in c++?

Tags: c++, linked-list

#### The problem:

Imagine there is a linked list class which has multiple methods to use. The main part of the code is like this:

```
int main ()
{
  List l;

  l.push_back (86);
  l.push_front (43);
  l.push_front (12);

  int intToSearchFor = 12;

  if (l.exists (intToSearchFor))
    {
      cout << "(" << intToSearchFor << ") found :)";
    }
  else
    {
      cout << "(" << intToSearchFor << ") not found :(";
    }
}
```

As you can see in this piece of code, the List class has two methods to prepend and append new items to the list. And also it has an iterator method which lets us loop over the items and check the data in each node.

#### The issue?

I want to create a method which check existence of an element. For example `l.exists(12)` should return either `true` or `false`.

#### My Solution:

1. Start to loop over the items with iterator.
2. Check if the item data is equal to the one you are looking for.
3. If it is equal then return `true`. Otherwise if there are more items in the list, move into the next item in the list and go to step 2.
4. If there are no more items in the list return `false`.

```
bool List::exists (int x)
{
  Iterator it = this->get_iterator ();
  do {
    
    if (it.current->data == x) {
        return true;
    }
    
    it.current = it.current->next;

  } while (it.has_more_elements ());

  return false;
}
```

#### Full answer:

http://cpp.sh/6cfdh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   while(it.current->data!=x && it.has_more_elements())
    it.current=it.current->next;
return (it.current->data==x)?true:false;
```

If `x` is not present and `it` reaches end of list, `it.current->data` will cause run time error as `it` may be `NULL`.

```
 while(it.has_more_elements() && it.current->data!=x)
   it.current = it.current->next;
 return it.current!=NULL;
```

Comment: @AliSamie: It might be clearer to define "not working", for example, what does the debugger tell you?

Comment: i just made a mistake rewriting the code it now works

Answer (score 1):

You should check whether a pointer points to nullptr **before** accessing data pointed by the pointer (see `has_more_elements()`).  Better naming may avoid some confusion.